# define code for different iphones

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to place an ad, while it looks perfect in the iPhone 5/5s it looks bad in the 4/4s.

Is there a way in my method to tell

```
if device == iphone4/4s 
    do this
if device == iphone5/5s 
    do that?
```

Thank you.

Comment: Set your Frame for 3.5 Inch (iPhone 4/4s)....

Comment: @user3396301 : Don't write separate code for iPhone4/iPhone5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the device based on the screen size.
get device screen size

```
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;
if(screenHeight > 480)
{
//iphone 5
}
else
{
//iphone 4or 4s or 3 or 3s
}
```

Note :
Window size(including status bar)
iPhone 4S (and earlier) -320 x 480 pts
    iPhone 5        -320 x 568 pts

Comment: please read question , please direct them on the right way.

Comment: yes Vineesh TP, i answered what he asked.

Comment: NO, he asked mistakenly we should have to direct them.

Comment: this worked like a charm, i can't use auto layout for what i need, thank you for answering MY QUESTION, and not what YOU BELIEVE I WANT TO ASK.

Answer (score 3):

Don't do separate code for iPhone4 and iPhone 5 use AutoLayout/ Auto resize.

[AutoLayout Introduction](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutinCode/AutoLayoutinCode.html

Answer (score 1):

Check the screen bounds

```
if ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568)
{
    //change the frame of the ad here
}
else
{
    //change the frame of the ad here
}
```

or use autolayout in your interface file

Comment: Not need to do separate code for iphone4/ iphone5